# uwsgi vassal magic variable

Tags: django, uwsgi, graphite, graphite-carbon

I'm running uwsgi 1.9.20 in emperor mode and sending all of my vassals' stats to a carbon/graphite server.  Looking good, except the `%n` magic variable doesn't return the "filename without extension" as specified in the [docs](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Configuration.html#magicvars), but rather the socket setting, e.g. `127_0_0_1:14002`.  Or at least that is what I see in graphite.

```
# uwsgi.ini
[uwsgi]
emperor = /usr/local/uwsgi/vassals/
emperor-tyrant = 1 
vacuum = 1
carbon = 172.12.2.4:2003
carbon-id = %n
# settings to apply to all vassals
vassal-set = plugin-dir=/usr/local/uwsgi/plugins 
vassal-set = enable-metrics=1 
vassal-set = carbon=172.12.2.4:2003
vassal-set = plugins=carbon
vassal-set = carbon-use-metrics=1
```

The emperor is started with:

```
uwsgi --ini /usr/local/uwsgi/uwsgi.ini
```

Example vassal config:

```
# bob.xml
<uwsgi>
    <pidfile>/home/bob/bob.pid</pidfile>
    <socket>127.0.0.1:14002</socket>
    <protocol>scgi</protocol>
    <pythonpath>/home/bob/pybin/bob</pythonpath>
    <virtualenv>/home/bob/pybin/bob-venv</virtualenv>
    <module>bob.wsgi</module>
    <workers>3</workers>
    <procname-prefix>bob: </procname-prefix>
    <buffer-size>8192</buffer-size>
    <daemonize>/home/bob/logs/bob.log</daemonize>
    <disable-logging />
    <master />
    <vacuum />
</uwsgi>
```

I also tried `vassal-set = carbon-id=%n`, but that shows up as just `uwsgi` in graphite.  What am I doing wrong with the magic variable here?

FYI Python version is 2.7.3 on CentOS 6.4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The carbon metric name is built as:

```
carbon-root.hostname.carbon-id
```

so you need to set both `carbon-root` and `carbon-id`

Comment: I may not have been clear on that.  In carbon, the metrics are seen as, for example: `uwsgi.somehostname.127_0_0_1:14002`.  I'd expect the `carbon-id` to be `bob`, since the vassal filename is `bob.xml`, however the vassal's `socket` is returned instead.

Comment: you should set carbon-id in the vassal file, even setting it with vassal-set will not work as %n is expanded as soon as possible

Comment: Setting `carbon-id` in the vassal file appears to the be best solution.  I was hoping to just reference the vassal filename, but this is sufficient and gives us more control I suppose.  Thanks.